# Delete or edit an unread push notification with AWS SNS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Sometimes a push notification needs to be edited after being sent.

Is there a way to remove (undo, delete, void) or edit (update, change) an unread push notification after [publishing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html) it through [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) [SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/index.html)?

I'm using the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html) to send push notifications from our [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) backend server:

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const sns = new aws.SNS();

...

// Apple iOS Push Notifications
sns.publish({
  Message: JSON.stringify({
    default: message,
    APNS: apnsPayload,
    APNS_SANDBOX: apnsPayload,
  }),
  TargetArn: this.apnsSnsArn,
  MessageStructure: 'json',
}).promise().catch(err => console.log(err));


// Android Push Notifications
sns.publish({
  Message: JSON.stringify({
    default: message,
    GCM: JSON.stringify({
      data: { title, message, data },
    }),
  }),
  TargetArn: this.fcmSnsArn,
  MessageStructure: 'json',
}).promise().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: No. That is not possible.

Comment: Can a silent push be triggered then that essentially instructs the app to wake up and update the push notification on the client itself?

Comment: I do not understand what you are suggesting.